# Is II a resonating structure of I?

Tags: resonance

Is the structure II a resonating structure of I? If yes, then how? Isn't the lone  pair on N non conjugated so as not to participate in resonance?

I [image: Structure I]
II [image: Structure II]

Comment: The bottom structure has a carbon with 5 bonds in the bottom ring.

Comment: Actually there are carbon atoms with 5 bonds almost everywhere.

Comment: @Mithoron. Almost everywhere in the structures depicted in the figure posted by the OP. :)

Comment: Ah, yeah. I see poor skill with drawing program there.

Comment: @Zhe you know I am not hexaccordinate carbon for nothing. I like so much these structures with 5 bonds carbons :D

Answer (score 3):

Note that *both* representations contain errors.

Under normal circumstances, the [valence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_(chemistry)) of uncharged carbon atoms in a molecule equal to four.

Hence, in the upper representation, the carbon bond to the nitrogen bears one valence to much.  Keeping the rest of the structure drawn as close to the original, your first drawing should look like the following:

[image]

In the lower representation, both the carbons binding towards oxygen are depicted as if carbon were pentavalent, which under normal circumstances does not occur.  In addition the central atom of nitrogen is drawn as if it were tetravalent.  There are instances of tetravalent nitrogen atoms in organic compounds, however these are positively charged (like the [tetrabutylammonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrabutylammonium_hydroxide) ion, or the [iminium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iminium) cation) on nitrogen.  Indeed the second (assuming a motif of $\ce{C=N=C}$) would be something not frequently seen, but *on paper* could be represented for example as

[image]

Answer (score -2):

There is a carbon atom in the second structure with 5 bonds. It is not a real structure nor a resonance structure of 1

Comment: I count more than one instance of "pentavalent carbon".

Comment: @Alchimista look at my username ^^

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C. This is quite an  outstanding nick! :)

Comment: @Alchimista yeah but it really exists ! :)

Comment: I know but it is indeed outstanding. By the way it could have been a real question with mistake forced by some "new to the user" programme. It is good that Burtonwood made a clear picture